# JComboBox not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I'm trying to put a JComboBox on my JFrame, if i clicked shows the contents of the combo, but it was not showed on the JFrame.

I already tried with: .setVisible(true), .setEnabled(true), etc.

Here is my code:

```
public class tryCode {
  private final JComboBox vehicleTypeBox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"HELLO WORLD", "OLA K ASE"});
  private JFrame frame;

  public tryCode() {
        frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        showComboBox();
   }

   public void showComboBox() {
        vehicleTypeBox.setBounds(10,80,100,30);
        vehicleTypeBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        frame.add(vehicleTypeBox);
   }
}
```

Any solution is welcome!. Thanks

Comment: where have you called showComboBox()

Comment: 1) You never add the comboBox to the frame. When you fix this problem, make sure you add the combo box to the frame before you make the frame visible. 2) Don't use a null layout!!! 3) Follow Java naming conventions. Class names start with an upper case character.

Comment: sorry, lack part of code, is called in the constructor :]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't see where you have changed your code to follow the suggestions that we have made. Also, how do we execute the code, there is no main() method?

Comment: i added all code for the Window class, but it very large, i need fix it :(

Answer (score 2):

You never call `showComboBox()` anywhere. If it is supposed to show up at startup you should call it in the constructor.

```
public tryCode() 
{
    frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // do not use null!
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    showComboBox();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I'd give you a +1 just for the use of a layout manager!  But you hit the problem on the head!

Comment: yes i tried, don't show the JCOmboBox, but it show the items when i clicked. look screenshots https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_y8aN4-TJMvTVd3SU13Uml4dzg/edit?usp=sharing https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_y8aN4-TJMvVVNONEVmSzA3MXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MateoOlaya, screenshots don't tell us anything. You've been given answers. I suspect you still are not following the advice given. We can't help until you post your SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

I just test your code with adding a main method.and it works.no problems.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TryCode {
  private final JComboBox vehicleTypeBox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"HELLO WORLD", "OLA K ASE"});
  private JFrame frame;

  public TryCode() {
        frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        showComboBox();
   }

   public void showComboBox() {
        vehicleTypeBox.setBounds(10,80,100,30);
        vehicleTypeBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        frame.add(vehicleTypeBox);
   }



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TryCode t=new TryCode();

    }

}
```